# Adding child node to list using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a ordered list (ol) of data in some predefined order. I need to add a new child node to the list when a button is clicked. The image shows the list data : [image]

For example, when I click the "Add" button on the List 3, it should create and append a new child node "List 3.3" to the parent node. But if I click List 4 "Add" button, it should create a new child node "List 4.1". 
The HTMl code is:

```
<div class="dd" id="tree">
    <ol class="list-tree dd3-list">
        <li class="item-tree item-tree-inner" data-id="136"></li> 
        <li class="item-tree item-tree-inner" data-id="137"></li>
        <li class="item-tree item-tree-inner" data-id="135">
            <ol class="list-tree dd3-list">
                <li class="item-tree item-tree-inner" data-id="138"></li>
                <li class="item-tree item-tree-inner" data-id="86"></li>
            </ol>
        </li>
        <li class="item-tree item-tree-inner" data-id="1"></li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

How can I accomplish this by using jQuery?

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) so far? It wouldn't hurt to show your actual html in addition to the pretty picture, so that we can see if you've set things up with classes, or...

Comment: Actually i thought it will be easy to understand using picture. :)
Now Edited and pasted the Html code too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should be something along these lines:

```
var handleAdd = function (event) {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ($this.children('ol').length > 0) {
        $('<li></li>').appendTo($this.children('ol'));
    } else {
        $('<ol><li></li></ol>').appendTo($this);
    }
    event.stopPropagation();
};
$(document).on('click', 'li', handleAdd);
```

Comment: I tried the code but it is creating only one child node also it does not let me create more node in newly created node. 

It is not working for the node that already have child node in it.

Comment: @user456064 Yes because I didn't have the newly added li elements to get the same event handler. Modified my code.

Comment: I dont know what is missing but now when i try to create child node, it adds one parent node and another child node at the same time...

Comment: @user456064 added stopPropagation()

Answer (score 1):

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/rahularyansharma/CfY5b/4/)

```
  <ol>
        <li>list1 <input type="button" value="add"/></li>
        <li>list2 <input type="button" value="add"/></li>
        <li>list3 <input type="button" value="add"/></li>
        <li>list4 <input type="button" value="add"/></li>
        <li>list5 <input type="button" value="add"/></li>
    </ol>
```

JQUERY

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

  $('body').on('click', 'ol li input', function(){
        $(this).parent().append('<ol><li>child node<input type="button" value="add" /></li></ol>');
    });
});
```